# Change the template according to user selection in joomla

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-extensions

I am working in joomla since last 2 years but now I got an different problem. My client want the template selection according to user selection. Means there are more then 4 templates are in joomla, one is default site template and according to user selection the template get changed and that will be applicable to his profile.

Comment: I think the metamod people have a template extension taht is similar but you could also look at how the back end handles it.

Comment: Please do some [research](http://extensions.joomla.org/) before asking here on StackOverflow, also maybe [Chameleon](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/style-a-design/templating/11173) will suit your needs.